# Focus textarea using css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm searching one javascript or html or css code that make change background color when i click in textarea i need something like this http://prntscr.com/bzsqgq

I tried with javascript but i can't do that its to hard, i tried onclick change background color with rgba something like blur.

```
$('.comment .body').on('click', function() {
    if($(this).hasClass('changing')) {
        $('.comment textarea').blur();
    }else {
        $('.comment textarea').focus();
    }

});


$('.comment textarea').on('focus',function() {
    $('.comment .body').addClass('changing').style('background-color: #FF0000;');
});         

$('.change-stamp textarea').on('blur',function() {
    $('.comment .body').removeClass('changing').text('background-color: transparent;');
});
```

Thanks who can help me.

Comment: not necessary you go just with css

Comment: you comment to express your opinion .. ok

Answer (score 1):

Add a `wrapper` and an `inner` element like this

```css
.wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px;
}
input:focus ~ .inner,
textarea:focus ~ .inner {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  left: 0; top: 0;
  width: 100%; height: 100%;
  background: yellow;
  border: 2px solid red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <input type="text">
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <textarea></textarea>
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var element = document.getElementsByClassName("chg_parent_on_focus")[0]
var parent = element.parentElement
element.onfocus = function(){
  parent.className = "cont active";
}
element.onblur = function(){
  parent.className = "cont"; 
}
```

```css
.cont{
 width:200px;
 background:red;
 padding:100px;
}
input{
  margin:10px;
  }
.cont.active{
 background:black;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
  <input class="chg_parent_on_focus"/>
</div>
```

Comment: I dont wanna change the textarea background color i wanna change the body color something like this http://prntscr.com/bzsqgq

Comment: I know, wait a bit