# Highlighting div and darker background

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm creating a site, but since I am stuck, I need some help.

I would like to create a div, which is highlighted when the user hovers over it or clicks it. For example on Facebook when we are writing a new post.

Here is a picture illustrating my idea:

[image: screenshot]

I want the background to be darker as if the site is "focusing" on the div.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to StackOverflow. Thanks for your question, but this is not a code writing service. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38684294/focus-textarea-using-css This question doesn't have an accepted answer but you can try the answers' code and if you still have issues, come back and ask (now providing some code).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I advise you using CSS selectors for this case. The `:hover` selector is used to add styling to an element. Like with an id of 'element'

```
#element { background : white; }

#element:hover { background : red; }
```

This way when the user is hovered over the element, the background is changing.

Other way is implementing `onmouseover` and `onmouseout` methods to you element, like:

```
<button id="element" onmouseover="mouseover()" onmouseout="mouseout()">
```

and using JavaScript to declare those methods, like this:

```
function mouseover()
{
   document.getElementById('element').style.backgroundColor = "red";
}

function mouseout()
{
   document.getElementById('element').style.backgroundColor = "white";
}
```

Or you can solve it similarly but easier with jQuery.

But this is the harder way. Read more about selectors [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp), about onmouseover [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmouseover.asp) and learn jQuery easily [here](https://www.codecademy.com/en/skills/make-an-interactive-website).

Egyébként: bojler eladó. :)

Answer (score 2):

Soooo firstly,
these are the Basics of JavaScript(jQuery) and CSS.
Here the key Element is

> z-index

z-index is value which set the display level of an element. The heighest element will dominate and overlap the others.

First you need an element you want to hover - named "element".

```
<div id="element">Click</div>
```

Secondly you need the the Dark-Zone Background. There you Go!

```
<div id="popup">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#popup {
 background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
 position: fixed;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 display: none;
 z-index: 98;
}

#element {
 position: relative;
 background-color: #FFF;
 height: 100px;
 width: 300px;
 margin: auto;
 z-index: 99;
}

#popup:hover {
 display: none;
}
```

jQuery(library):

```
$("#element").on("mouseover", function(){
 $("#popup").show();
}).on("mouseout", function(){
 $("#popup").hide();
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9aueqsfr/